# using python how do I apply sine function to a column (dataframe) with values in degrees. I want answer in degrees

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have around 250+ values of theta. However below is just an example

```
Theta
0
30
45
60
90
```

expected output

```
0
0.5
0.7071
0.8660
1
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: df1["Sine"]=np.sin(np.deg2rad(df2))
print(df1)

##df2 is theta in degrees and I want to add it to df1 data

output
9.659258e-01
 9.659258e-01
1.000000e+00

i dont want the "e"

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.sin`:

```
np.sin(np.deg2rad(df.Theta))
```

Output:

```
0    0.000000
1    0.500000
2    0.707107
3    0.866025
4    1.000000
Name: Theta, dtype: float64
```

Comment: it is giving me output as 1.000000e+00

i dont want the e

Answer (score 0):

To convert these degrees into sine values, we need to first convert the degrees to radians, *then* use `math.sin()` to find the values. You can convert the degrees into radians by using `math.radians()`:

```
from math import sin, radians

degrees = [0, 30, 45, 60, 90]
sine = [sin(radians(d)) for d in degrees]
print(sine)
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 0.49999999999999994, 0.7071067811865475, 0.8660254037844386, 1.0]
```

---

---

If you prefer rounded numbers, you can use the built-in method, `round()`:

```
sine = [round(sin(radians(d)),4) for d in degrees]
print(sine)
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 0.5, 0.7071, 0.866, 1.0]
```

Comment: Recommend using `np.sin` and `np.deg2rad` instead of `math`'s equivalences since the former are vectorized.

Comment: Not working for a large df of 250+ values. Please check

Comment: @DK It should work, regardless of size. You can post the result and the expected result.

Comment: it is giving result as 1.000000e+00    I do not want the e and want the absolute value only be it positive or negative